# undef value and printing it

Tags: perl, undef

This is my first time using Perl.

In Perl threads, the return value of the `threads->exit()` subroutine is `undef` value if the context is scalar.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use threads;

$t=threads->create({"context"=>"scalar"},
                    sub { threads->exit();});
$re = $t->join();
print "##################\n";
print "$re\n\n";
print "##################\n";
print (undef) . "TES\n";
print "##################\n"
```

The output is:

```
##################


##################
##################
```

Why in `print "$re\n\n";` the print is executed but not in `print (undef) . "TES\n";`?
Even though the `$re` is `undef`.

and I made a test to ensure that $re is undefined of not.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use threads;

$t=threads->create({"context"=>"scalar"},
                    sub { threads->exit();});
$re = $t->join();
print "##################\n";
print "$re\n\n" if ! defined $re;
print "##################\n";
print (undef) . "TES\n";
print "##################\n"
```

and I go the same output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print (undef) . "TES\n";
```

is same as

```
(print (undef)) . "TES\n";
```

so you're concatenating result of `print` with string.

What you want is

```
print ((undef) . "TES\n"); # or print undef() . "TES\n";
```

Comment: or just `print undef . "TES\n";` :)

Comment: @friedo `Warning: Use of "undef" without parentheses is ambiguous..`

Comment: @mpapec, which is silenced by using `undef()`

Comment: @friedo, `print undef() . "TES\n";` would avoid the warning.

Comment: @ikegami it seems that both examples are utilizing parentheses

Comment: @mpapec, what does that mean? My comment was in reply to your comment to friedo.